# Problem with the verb tense in a relative clause

Tags: tense, sentence-structure, verb-forms

The sentence is

> the background music **that's gone through Louis's mind** when he discovered his love for Lestat"

and I don't know which verb forms would be correct in the **relative clause** and why.

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Comment: F.H.H., In an attempt to avoid a proofreading charge, I have rephrased your question to make it one specific to appropriate word choice.  This is how I've interpreted your question and also how I've answered it.  Please make sure that I'm correct in my understanding of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in selecting the correct **verb form** for *to go* in the relative clause

> that **[verb form of *to go*]** through Louis's mind

This must be compatible with the adverbial clause of time

> when he discovered his love for Lestat

*Discovered* is a simple past tense indicating a completed act in past time, and *has gone* (*that's* is a contraction for *that has*) is in the present perfect, which covers some past interval up to the present.  That won't work because it covers time past the discovery of love.

You have the following reasonable choices.

- the **simple past**

  > the background music that **went** through Louis's mind

  Coupled with *when*, this means the music happened at the same time
  as the  discovery.
- the **past progressive**:

  > the background music that **was going** through Louis's mind

  This emphasizes that the music was playing before and during the
  discovery.
- the **past perfect**

  > the background music that **had gone** through Louis's mind

  This indicates a past action completed before a past event, which
  would be taken here to be the moment after the discovery.  In other words, the discovery of love triggered some music.
- the **past perfect progressive**:

  > the background music that **had been going** through Louis's mind

the progressive indicates an ongoing event during the defined past interval.

Comment: I've just read the question (and edited) and the main verb of the sentence is missing. I think the OP should clarify what the question is about.